# Facebook star ratings on website

Tags: facebook

I'm new to Facebook API and trying to get a page's star ratings on a web page, but not getting far...

```
<?php 

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '{API_ID_HERE}',
      'app_secret' => '{API_SECRET_HERE}',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
      //'default_access_token' => '{ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE}', // optional
    ]);


    /* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
    /* make the API call */
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/PAGE_ID_HERE/ratings'
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    /* handle the result */
?>
```

I don't expect it too be right 100% but trying to a connection at least, but I keep getting;

Class 'FacebookRequest' not found

Which I've googled but not found anything constructive, I've got composer etc. but not sure what I'm missing

Cheers

**Update**

I found a solution to that error, but not getting a whole new one which doesn't make sense...

*Notice: Undefined variable: session in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptests\php-graph-sdk\index.php on line 33*

*Warning: parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptests\php-graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Url\FacebookUrlManipulator.php on line 109*

*Warning: parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptests\php-graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Url\FacebookUrlManipulator.php on line 43*

*Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptests\php-graph-sdk\index.php on line 41*

```
<?php 

  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

  use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

  // PHP GRAPH SDK 5.5
  function QueryToRetrieveUserThroughID(string $id) {

   $newFacebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
       'app_id' => '',
       'app_secret' => '',
       'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
   ]);

   $newFacebookApp = $newFacebook->getApp();
   $response = $newFacebook->get($id, '');
   // or $response = $newFacebook->get($id);

   $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
 }

 $request = new FacebookRequest(
 $session,
 'GET',
 '//ratings',
 array(
   'fields' => 'rating'
 )
);

   $response = $request->execute();
   $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
   /* handle the result */

?>
```

Comment: Are you using v4 of the PHP SDK here? If so, I would recommend that you switch to the current v5 first of all. Things have changed a bit between those two versions, v5 doesn’t use such a session object any more. Suggest you go check the examples under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted to get a general feeling for how to work with this SDK first.

Comment: I started with v4 but moved onto v5 but still not getting far....

Comment: Can you update the question with current code? What exactly is not working? You’re aware that you need a page access token to get the ratings of a page, yes?

Comment: Everything after **update** is the current code and yeah, got page access token which I followed another tutorial to set up.